# Equation solver to solve for x but short and simple equations

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I need help to create a program that can solve for x in a simple equation such as X+3=5 or 4-X=6. If anyone can help that would be amazing.

Comment: This is too broad at the moment. You should specify exactly what operations are allowed and add enough detail so that the question can be answered.

Comment: Welcome to SO, which is not a code writing service.  After you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), I suggest reading the guide on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Are your equations only addition and subtraction?

Comment: The operation that are required are division, multiplication, subtraction, and addition and it has to be done without any importing any modules

Comment: Why without importing any modules?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want [`sympy`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html).

```
>>> from sympy.solvers import solve
>>> from sympy import Symbol
>>> x = Symbol('x')
>>> solve(x + 3 - 5, x)
[2]
>>> solve(4 - x - 6, x)
[-2]
```

Comment: Note: if you're looking to implement something like sympy's `solve` on your own, I'd recommend starting with an easier project (learn the basics of Python first at the very least so that you can start to conceptualize what an implementation of this sort of equation solver would have to do) and working your way up.  This isn't a good beginner project.